# Swift Adding Padding to Base64 String is Returning Smaller String

Tags: swift, base64

I have an image that I have converted to base64 that is failing when I try to decode because it is not divisible by 4.  I added code to check for this and add padding appropriately.  This code works for smaller strings that I test but when using larger strings it actually returns a smaller string with hundreds of less characters.

I am using this for image processing so the strings are base64 encoded images.

```
    imageView = imageButton.backgroundImage(for: UIControl.State.normal)
    if var strBase64 = imageView.toBase64() {
        print("char count 1 ", strBase64.count)
        let remainder = strBase64.count % 4
        if remainder > 0 {
            print("remainder is greater than zero = ", remainder)
            print("char count 2 ", strBase64.count)
            let strBase64 = strBase64.padding(toLength: strBase64.count + 4 - remainder, withPad: "=", startingAt: 0)
            print("char count 3 ", strBase64.count)
        }

        if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64) {
            if let decodedimage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                print("unwrapped")
            }
        } else {
            print("failed")
        }
    }

extension UIImage{
    func toBase64() -> String? {
        guard let imageData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else { return nil }
        return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
char count 1  42054
remainder is greater than zero =  2
char count 2  42054
char count 3  41419
failed
```

Update:

I removed the option for lineLength64Characters which seems to have fixed the problem but I am not sure why.  I do notice that all pics now are returned as multiples of 4 so that may be part of it.  Thank you for help to users below.

Comment: Please provide an actual test example. I do not believe that an image properly converted to base64 will not convert back to image data. The problem is more likely in the way you upload / download the data. Show your entire chain and perhaps provide a sample image?

Comment: I am not downloading or uploading the data, just storing the encoded data into a string and trying to decode later.  When the base64 data is divisible by 4 and no padding needed it works, when it is not then it fails.

Comment: Cool, can you provide an example image and example code for both encoding and decoding? In other words, everything needed to reproduce the basic issue. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I update the code here to show both encoding and decoding.  The image I using is one of the default iPhone simulator images, the first yellow flower pic.  I would upload it here if I knew how.

Comment: Where does your code print “char count 4/5/6”?

Comment: Sorry that was a cut and paste error, updated.

Comment: Note that the padded string is assigned to a *local* variable `strBase64` whose scope is restricted to the  `if remainder > 0 { ... }` block. Therefore the `decodedimage` is still constructed from the original, unpadded Base64 string.

Comment: Thank you Martin that does make sense now and would have been part of the if not the whole problem.  Clearly I was struggling in multiple ways with this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pad anything *manually*, just add the `ignoreUnknownCharacters` option

```
if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) { ...
```

Or decode the data without options and omit the `lineLength64Characters` option when encoding the data

```
return imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

and delete

```
  print("char count 1 ", strBase64.count)
    let remainder = strBase64.count % 4
    if remainder > 0 {
        print("remainder is greater than zero = ", remainder)
        print("char count 2 ", strBase64.count)
        let strBase64 = strBase64.padding(toLength: strBase64.count + 4 - remainder, withPad: "=", startingAt: 0)
        print("char count 3 ", strBase64.count)
    }
```

Comment: not true, on iOS Data(base64Encoded:options:) must be correctly padded to be divisible by 4 without reminder.